# Passing a function pointer from an array of function pointers as a template argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I would like to pass a function pointer from an array of function pointers as a template argument. My code seems to compile using MSVC even though Intellisense complains that something is wrong. Both gcc and clang fail to compile the code.

Consider the following example:

```
static void test() {}

using FunctionPointer = void(*)();

static constexpr FunctionPointer functions[] = { test };

template <FunctionPointer function>
static void wrapper_function()
{
    function();
}

int main()
{
    test();  // OK
    functions[0]();  // OK

    wrapper_function<test>();  // OK
    wrapper_function<functions[0]>();  // Error?
}
```

**MSVC** compiles the code but Intellisense gives the following error: `invalid nontype template argument of type "const FunctionPointer"`

**gcc** fails to compile with the following message:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:19:33: error: no matching function for call to 'wrapper_function<functions[0]>()'
   19 |  wrapper_function<functions[0]>();  // Error?
      |                                 ^
<source>:8:13: note: candidate: 'template<void (* function)()> void wrapper_function()'
    8 | static void wrapper_function()
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:8:13: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:19:30: error: '(FunctionPointer)functions[0]' is not a valid template argument for type 'void (*)()'
   19 |  wrapper_function<functions[0]>();  // Error?
      |                   ~~~~~~~~~~~^
<source>:19:30: note: it must be the address of a function with external linkage
```

**clang** fails to compile with the following message:

```
<source>:19:2: error: no matching function for call to 'wrapper_function'
        wrapper_function<functions[0]>();  // Error?
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:8:13: note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'function'
static void wrapper_function()
            ^
1 error generated.
```

**Questions:**

Is `wrapper_function<functions[0]>();` valid or not?

If it isn't, is there anything I can do to pass `functions[0]` as a template argument to `wrapper_function`? My goal is to construct a new array of function pointers at compile time, with the content `{ wrapper_function<functions[0]>, ..., wrapper_function<functions[std::size(functions) - 1]> }`.

Comment: Hmm that is interesting, I thought the issue was that you were using a value (a pointer) instead of a type. But even `wrapper_function<decltype(functions[0])>()` doesn't compile.

Comment: Seems to work in C++17... now to find the difference in standardese...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expression `wrapper_function<functions[0]>();` is forbidden because of the following:

> 14.3.2 Template non-type arguments [temp.arg.nontype]
>
> A template-argument for a non-type, non-template template-parameter
>   shall be one of:
>
> [...]
>
> — a constant expression (5.19) that designates the address of an
>   object with static storage > duration and external or internal linkage
>   or a function with external or internal linkage, including function
>   templates and function template-ids but excluding non-static class
>   members, expressed (ignoring parentheses) as & id-expression, except
>   that the & may be omitted if the name refers to a function or array
>   and shall be omitted if the corresponding template-parameter is a
>   reference; [...]

It is forbidden to use pointers as non-type template arguments other than of the form `&id` so, basically, following would work:

```cpp
static void test() {}

using FunctionPointer = void(*)();

static constexpr FunctionPointer functions[] = { test };

template <FunctionPointer function>
static void wrapper_function()
{
    function();
}

int main()
{
    test();  // OK
    functions[0]();  // OK

    wrapper_function<test>();  // OK
    wrapper_function<&test>();  // OK
}
```

and following snippet won't work when compiled with C++14 option:

```cpp
constexpr auto func = &test;
wrapper_function<func>();
```

When compiled with C++17 option, your approach and the one above would both work:

```cpp
int main()
{
    test();  // OK
    functions[0]();  // OK

    wrapper_function<test>();  // OK
    wrapper_function<&test>();  // OK
    wrapper_function<func>();  // OK

    wrapper_function<functions[0]>();  // OK
}
```

See [live](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEN15b0AGTy1MAOWMAjTMRCSAbKQAOqBYXVaPUMTM15ffzU6GztHIxc3T0VlTFVAhgJmYgJg41NzZJUo2gysghiHZ1d3LwVM7NzQgrqyiriEmoBKRVQDYmQOAHIpAGZbZEMsAGpxEZ0qA1o0ujZZ7HEABgBBTa2WtWQpgDdUPHQpgkw6iE6ZgHZZO4ARXd2Df1EpgDFF5doABVO9FcMxGT2Op3QEAAVJ0brNZNtdvs8Ic0LQ6pgAB7eYjfX7FQG2S54hZLYoKcQAVlkVPBs3pDwuVwI9xeI0RO22lyM3mEl1BOh%2B5MCROBpIJgTWyMyBwhZymAHdiMxvN5XAB9Ml/eFIh67KaGqba4rwjmvZ6vbbozE4vHMAxEY2/UH0zyXOoIq1bYlTIzMWy6nb67ZG5nXToIw0AemjUwA8gBpA1Gk2BSk0jbUp5m6QxuNJ71h5Wq9XELWSuizHQeghrXP5hPJ0NGktqzVpqtzKQeWv1yMcxuFluGttlisirvzX79qNTWNNoutlXt8ud2jV9cZ6RZumzwcL4fBp6DbqsECDKmDUimQYba%2BoC86ORyKYKXr9TAzSQjTjXggXvenTdAA1iAVLcAAdCMGwABwbAAnCMCEIdwdx3PBdxeOegzcNet73qQj6DNeCggBspAAXep6kHAsAwIgKCoLyeDsGQFAQGgLFsSgwiiAhGwUVQrEkmREBOIB15OLYWQAJ4Xn%2BpBcUYWgEPGtCsPJ1GkFg/qiOwkk6XgxCpGoRxXIZ2KpI6QyEcSyiGaweBOCqxCyXoWAKf%2BxB4EYXndDQ9BMGwHA8Pwgh8WIL4yEIzlkZA3SoN4FIXgAtHU6AMhIMhyJwdykSkfyaNojSmJwpCWG0VRuOVEQBHQpWCHVxRVfE1TlUoRTpPUOT6HkgidaZ3WtLYlRtTVig9Y1HU9a1HScN0759AMXBnheV43oZxFYrBHipR43BTBMIjAFMCGQRsF1TBAuCECQ36/qQUx6NxIKjAtz3RdI/6ScBpBgdwVKQQhWFUpwGyeJIUOA1SQgXnhpB%2BWDF3cJIsHg4hsF3AhkhUiMXgEQ%2BF6keRlG/bRDEQEgvQEN4jrkJQXHeKx7UVfgRATYFjAsAZYVtv5cOXvhW0Xu9SqEAgUw7XtB1HZFZ0XRdP3UX9CCYMwWBuDcgsI353CwcDVJ3JwsEoRsnCSBsdzcAdm3acRJMUVRQGgWYQMeAhnACR4glUlDXuSLwOEjML9vE2TKtrYMkih4RDsRy7pDmcQ/gaNwQA)

Comment: Not only the form `&id`, but also `id` is allowed for functions, as you are demonstrating in the example and a null pointer value is explicitly allowed in constant expression form.

Comment: C++17 replaces that with a "[converted constant expression](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.arg.nontype#2)", i.e. it allows to chain constant expressions so `wrapper_function<func>()` will also work.

Comment: Ok will check and update the answer after I write it in whole. Tnx